# JS statement gets executed in Safari, only in new tabs, but it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

I am having a really weird problem that I can't wrap my head around,the code below is supposed to make an XMLHTTPRequest if an alert window is closed in less than XY ms.

It works in all browsers and doesn't trigger the loadApi() function when I visit, just in Safari it gets executed no matter how long I wait until I close the alert.

But this only happens whenever I open a fresh tab in Safari and then visit the page, if I visit the same page again in the same tab the code doesn't get executed.

```js
var a = window.performance.now();
    alert('yo yo yo');
var b = window.performance.now();


if ((b - a) < 80) {
    console.log('yes');
    loadApi(); // this makes the XMLHTTPRequest which triggers a DB insert
}
```

And it gets even weirder, in Safari, when I visit in a fresh tab the code gets executed and does the XMLHTTPRequest, but the console.log() never triggers. Console just shows up empty.

Is that a Safari bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, the problem is that Safaris alert/prompt etc are not blocking the browser anymore for some time now.

So it seems that JS continues execution, sometimes, even after an alert is fired.

The solution was to start the counter, fire the alert, and then wrap the rest of the code in a setTimeout with a very short delay, I used 5ms.

That fixes it